# passing file name to validation class

Tags: php

I have been receiving this notice and I don't understand why or how to fix it?

Notice: Undefined index: in /website/classes/Validate.php on line 56 Warning: exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty in /website/classes/Validate.php on line 56

This is what I am doing to get this notice.

```
$validate = new Validate();

if($validate->fileCheck('file')){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "failed";
}
```

That is where I thought I am sending the file name to the class which I then use in the class like this.

```
public function fileCheck($name){
    $allowed = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);

    $file = exif_imagetype($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']);
    if(in_array($file, $allowed)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If anyone could help me understand why it is throwing this Notice and how to solve it I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: `$_FILES[$name]` is not set.

Comment: @marekful how do you mean?

Comment: The error means that whatever the `$name` variable holds, that's a non-existent index in the `$_FILES` array. So you get 2 notices, first for the undefined index and the 2nd for not passing a file name to `exif_imagetype`

Comment: @marekful I should add it does do the check and returns the correct result  depending on the file type